# Difference between $getAuth and $onAuth in angularfire

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

I was reading `angularfire` docs, and i found two similar services `$getAuth` and `$onAuth` given by `firebase` and both are written for checking user authentication. But i can't found any differences between both of them, can anybody describe them for me ?

and i also want to know that what is the good scenario to use each of these services. Thanks

[link of official documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-getauth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for `$getAuth()` says:

> Synchronously retrieves the current authentication state of the client

While for `$onAuth()` it says:

> Listens for changes to the client’s authentication state. The provided callback will fire when the client’s authenticate state changes.

So you'd call `$getAth()` in your code if you need to know whether the user is authenticated. Say that you want to use a different price in a calculation when the user is authenticated:

```
var productPrice = 50;
$scope.price = auth.$getAuth() ? 0.8 * productPrice : productPrice;
```

If on the other hand you'd want to do something based on *when* the user is authenticated, you'd use `$onAuth()`. A typical example would be to route the user to a different URL when they sign-in/get signed out.